# can I overflow the stack by spawning object on the heap?

Tags: c++

let's look at this quick example :

## Angel.hh

```
#include <string>

class Angel
{
  public :

  Angel( std::string n
       , std::string l )
  : name(n)
  {
    location = new std::string(l);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
      nbrOfFeathers+=i*i;
    }
  };

  ~Angel(  )
  {
    delete location;
  };

  std::string name;
  std::string* location;
  int nbrOfFeathers;
};
```

## main.cc

```
#include "Angel.hh"
#include <iostream>

int main(  )
{
  std::string locationA( "Pandemonium" );
  std::string locationB( "Purgatory" );

  Angel angel1( "Angel of Death" , locationB );
  std::cout << angel1.name << " is in " << *angel1.location << std::endl;

  Angel* angel2 = new Angel( "Angel of the Apocalypse", locationA );
  std::cout << angel2->name << " is in " << *angel2->location << std::endl;

  delete angel2;
}
```

as we can see `angel1`is stored on the stack, while `angel2`is stored on the heap. If I read only the header (`Angel.hh`) I think `name` would be stored on the stack while `location` would be stored on the heap.

I wonder if what I assert is true. Because I have in my mind to use the stack in preference for variables with a short lifetime, like¹ the integer `i`, and to preferably not using the stack for objects who can grow in numbers during the running time of the application. If my assert is true, can I overflow the stack by spawning angels on the heap (because of `name`) ? where `i` is stored ?

---

¹ in that case is not really important, it's just an example...

Comment: what do you mean by "nested"? it seem as though you were using this word for something completely different. are you talking about the loop? or…?

Comment: Only the pointer to your angle2 object lives on the stack.  Yes, you could overflow that, but you'd probably run out of heap long before then - and remember that the local pointer only lives in this scope and not beyond so that once you leave this function, that pointer is freed/lost.  Just how many Angels are you making?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant ok maybe a problem of my english skill... I thought nested as a synonim of stored

Comment: @MichaelDorgan "Just how many Angels are you making?" actually it's only an example, but I'm for example working on game engine, where I cannot know at 'priori' the number of entities that will be created

Comment: @MichaelDorgan the pointer to angel2 isn't on the heap ?

Comment: 'std::string' is a relative tiny object, and the 'std::string' (object) size never grows. In other words `Angel* angel2 = new Angel` and `location = new std::string` are pointless

Comment: @DieterLücking again it's only an example, moreover it's not necessarily "tiny". it depend of the hardware

Comment: @bob-theunholymetalmachine: The thing it points to is, yes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit true! the thing is I coding for years now, and never thought about that before...

Comment: @bob-theunholymetalmachine: That's fine; you shouldn't care about "stack" vs "heap" unless you're an embedded developer.

Comment: The storage that backs std::string will be on the heap, so the amount of stack consumed by angel1 and angel2 is identical.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I like to know what happend behind the hood. Also I'm interested by coding for embedded platform to. More over I didn't learn coding at school, but I guess my question could be a such question a teacher can ask at an exam... so I consider this question as a basic fundamental of coding

Comment: @bob-theunholymetalmachine: It may well be. It's just not a basic fundamental of C++. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit by coding I don't necessarily mean C++, in fact in my head I was more thinking about C when I wrote this... (because we were talking about embedded stuff)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit (ok I was going out of the question with this comment since my question is c++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me descibe in better detail what is going on for you - memory wise:

```
Angel angel1( "Angel of Death" , locationB );
std::cout << angel1.name << " is in " << *angel1.location << std::endl;
```

In this code, the entire `Angel` structure is located on the stack.  This does not include code within `Angel` that may also allocate to the heap (if it included pointers that were allocated and such), but everything declared within `Angel` is on the stack.

```
Angel* angel2 = new Angel( "Angel of the Apocalypse", locationA );
std::cout << angel2->name << " is in " << *angel2->location << std::endl;
```

Here, only a pointer to `Angel` lives on the stack, but the entire contents of the `Angel` class/struct live on the heap.  Notice we must use the `->` operator to access the structures.  This means that we are using a pointer to get to the data on the heap.  In detail:

```
std::string name;  
std::string* location;
int nbrOfFeathers;
```

Would be allocated to the heap in Angel2.

I hope this clears things up for you a bit.

Comment: so with `angel2` the integer `i` is on the heap too ? (you just mess angel1 and angel2 in the second part of your answer)

Comment: `i` is just a temporary variable on the stack of the constructor, is has nothing to do with angel2, its also gets freed right after the constructor call is finished

Comment: Actually, `i` is on the stack.  The code that Angel runs still has access to the stack, so its local vars would use the stack.  What goes on the heap is all memory associated with Angel.  I'll edit my response to show this.

Comment: Be careful about spreading misconceptions. Prefer to talk about _storage duration_ unless a specific implementation and platform have been asked about. "Stack" and "heap" are very misleading words to use in a pure C++ sense.

Comment: This might be a good time to educate me then.  How exactly and "Stack" and "Heap" misleading?  Maybe I'm too old school, but I was under the impression that those terms meant concrete things on any platform and were language agnostic.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit tell me more, could you point to some web articles/book ?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Can you name a platform where the terms do not apply (where the memory layout of the program at run time would be surprising), with the default allocators? Also, the standard is full of "stack", in the context of unwinding. It is an appropriate metaphor for objects which are created and destroyed in (reverse) order, like those with automatic storage duration. I also fail to see how "heap" is "very misleading" since it is basically a synonym for free store. While it is good to be exact when appropriate I feel like being subjected to political correctness guardians.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: lol I knew someone would roll out the "can you name an implementation that..." counter-argument. It begs the question, because the entire point of coding to standards rather than implementations is to avoid thinking in terms of non-guaranteed, situation-specific chance occurrences and to instead think in terms of deliberately abstracted concepts that leave you no chance of failure on any compliant system. It's a fail-safe system. _(cont.)_

Comment: _(cont.)_ It's a system of programming in which you do not _have_ to ask "are there implementations on which..." because you know that what you are doing is guaranteed safe on all of them. Always. No matter what. Now, tomorrow, forever. Whether I can think of one that doesn't fit it, on demand, off the top of my head (I can't; I'm drunk and can't be arsed!) is entirely by definition besides the point. _(cont.)_

Comment: _(cont.)_ I can't for the life of me understand why anyone would go out of their way to teach the opposite. I concede that in practice there are circumstances where you _must_ consider specifics, but this question is tagged [tag:c++], not [tag:some-particular-implemenation-and-scenario]. In short, I think you're looking at it backwards.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: They're language agnostic, but platform specific, and that's entirely the problem. Here we are teaching the language, not the platform. Therefore the terms are out of place.

Answer (score 1):

> If I read only the header (`Angel.hh`) I think name would be stored on the stack while location would be stored on the heap.

But as you know thinking that would be wrong, so don't think it!  You should instead think that `name` would be embedded in the `Angel` object, wherever that's constructed.

> Because I have in my mind to use the stack in preference for variables with a short lifetime, like¹ the integer i, and to preferably not using the stack for objects who can grow in numbers during the running time of the application.

That's a good rule of thumb.  For PC-oriented Operating Systems and C++ environments, stacks often default to 1 to 8MB in size, so any data getting into the tens of kilobytes, or even smaller data on the stack of recursive functions, would best be dynamically allocated (with `new`, or by storing elements in a Standard Library container that managed dynamic memory for you).

> If my assert is true, can I overflow the stack by spawning angels on the heap (because of name) ? where i is stored ?

No - as above the assertion was false:  when you `new` an `Angel`, `name` is dynamically allocated and you can't overflow the stack.  Basically, the stack's only used for automatic, local variables, which are automatically destructored and the memory reclaimed as functions exit, or even more local scopes like `for (...) { }`, `while (...) { }`, `do { } while (...);`, `if (...) { }` or plain old `{ }` inside a function.

Comment: "storing elements in a Standard Library container that managed dynamic memory for you" I do that, for exemple whith `glib::refptr` . I also though to build a "memory pool" for my game engine, but I will try to use `osg::ref_ptr` since I choice to use OSG as 3D renderer. "No - as above the assertion was false: when you new an Angel, name is dynamically allocated and you can't overflow the stack." ok so to summarize, `name` is harmless but If I create a lot of angels that use a lot of local variables `i` (it's just for understand) I could overflow it, right ?

Comment: @bob-theunholymetalmachine "If I create a lot of angels that use a lot of local variables" - ahhh, but the memory for the local variables in functions is transient, only while the functions are running, so however many `Angel` objects you have, there'll be at most one `i` per thread as you're calling the constructor.

Comment: Ok, I understand with all comments on this page, I should not worry about local variables used in functions. But, (sorry if I look to be annoying, I just want to be sure to understand) if I add a function to `Angel` with an infinite loop where a single local variable is used, it's not transient anymore, so I can overflow, right ? (again sorry, because I really feel like pushing... )

Comment: @bob-theunholymetalmachine: no need to apologise - every programmer's had to learn this some time or other. If you've got an infinite loop, the *same* memory will be used for variable inside the loop no matter how many times the code iterates. For example, if you say `std::string s; while (getline(cin, s)) { std::string t = s + s; std::cout << t; }`, then `getline()` reuses the same `s`. and `t` is recreated in the same memory each time through the loop. But if you've got infinite *recursion* - where your function calls itself ad infinitum - then and only then will you run out of memory.